# Unable to add string into an mutable array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to upload assignments into a table in an different view controller. First when i click on the upload button this code runs.

```
- (IBAction)uploadAssignment:(id)sender {
    nameOfAssignmentAsString = self.nameOfAssignment.text;
    NSLog(@"%@", nameOfAssignmentAsString);
    NSInteger row;
    row = [self.subjectPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    subjectOfAssignmentAsString = [subjectArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"%@", subjectOfAssignmentAsString);
    NSDate *deadline = [self.deadlinePicker date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    deadlineOfAssignmentAsString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:deadline];
    NSLog(@"%@",deadlineOfAssignmentAsString);

    HomeworkViewController *HVC;
    [HVC.nameOfAssignmentInAnArray addObject:nameOfAssignmentAsString];
    [HVC.SubjectOfAssignmentInAnArray addObject:subjectOfAssignmentAsString];
    [HVC.deadlineOfAssignmentInAnArray addObject:deadlineOfAssignmentAsString];
    NSLog(@"%@",HVC.nameOfAssignmentInAnArray.count);
}
```

then in my HomeworkViewController.h this is the code

```
@interface HomeworkViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {

    int i;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainMenu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *homeworkButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *uploadButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *nameOfAssignmentInAnArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *SubjectOfAssignmentInAnArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *deadlineOfAssignmentInAnArray;
```

I did initialise it in my HomeworkViewController.m file. But for some reason the string is not being added into the array.

Comment: `HVC` has not been initialized

Comment: how would i do that. Sorry but i am just a beginner

Comment: What file is your first code segment in?

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying

Comment: `- (IBAction)uploadAssignment:(id)sender {`

etc... What @implementation is that a part of?

Answer (score 0):

You declare HVC but never assign a value to it. Therefore it cannot hold anything in itself. But for some reason the designers of Objective-C decided it's not an error to send messages to nil objects, so this might not be noticed.

Comment: how do i assign a value to HVC

Comment: @ChandrasekaranDinesh That depends on what you are trying to do. Usually view controllers are instantiated from storyboards or xib files, unless they're already existing somewhere.

Comment: my view controller  is instantiated from the main.storyboard